# Extremely Odd Behavior with Simple UDP Server/Client. UDP stops after about 10 Seconds

Tags: c, arduino, udp, raspberry-pi3, microcontroller

I have two Arduino WiFi Rev 2 boards. One is a Server, which creates an Access Point called “MyAP” with a password. The other is the client which connects to the Access Point.  This works up to this point:

[image]

As you can see, the Client on the left successfully sends '1' to the Server. However, it stops after about 5 seconds. I did some debugging and I can see that the UDP packets are being sent. I also ran a script that essentially "reconnected" if the WiFi strength equaled '0', to which it would sucesfully reconnect. The problem lays somewhere with the IP address. I believe it somehow forgets the Server's IP address. Here is the Client/Server code

```
//SERVER
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include "arduino_secrets.h"

char ssid[] = "MyAP";        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "PWD";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)


int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiUDP Udp;
unsigned int localPort = 6555;    
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE]; 


void setup() {
    //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
    }

    Serial.println("Access Point Web Server");

    // check for the WiFi module:
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
        Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
        // don't continue
        while (true);
    }

    String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
    if (fv < WIFI_FIRMWARE_LATEST_VERSION) {
        Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
    }

    // by default the local IP address of will be 192.168.4.1
    // you can override it with the following:
    WiFi.config(IPAddress(192, 168, 4, 1));

    // print the network name (SSID);
    Serial.print("Creating access point named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    // Create open network. Change this line if you want to create an WEP network:
    status = WiFi.beginAP(ssid, pass);
    if (status != WL_AP_LISTENING) {
        Serial.println("Creating access point failed");
        // don't continue
        while (true);
    }

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
    //CHANGE2
    // start the web server on port 80
    //server.begin();
    Udp.begin(localPort);

    // you're connected now, so print out the status
    printWiFiStatus();
}

void loop() {

    // if there's data available, read a packet
    int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
    if (packetSize) {
       // Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
      //  Serial.println(packetSize);

        IPAddress remoteIp = Udp.remoteIP();
      //  Serial.print(remoteIp);
      //  Serial.print(", port ");
      //  Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

        // read the packet into packetBufffer
        int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer,2);
        if (len > 0) {
            packetBuffer[len] = 0;
        }
      //  Serial.println("Contents:");
        Serial.println(packetBuffer);

       // printWiFiStatus();
    } 
}

void printWiFiStatus() {
    // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
    Serial.print("SSID: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

    // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
    IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
    Serial.print("IP Address: ");
    Serial.println(ip);

    // print where to go in a browser:
    Serial.print("Listening...");
    Serial.println(ip);

}
```

And the Client:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>



int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

char ssid[] = "MyAP";        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "PWD";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)


IPAddress destinationIP(192, 168, 4, 1);  // Address of target machine
unsigned int destinationPort = 6555;      // Port to send to
 unsigned int localPort = 9999;      // Port to send to



// A UDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);


  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  printWifiStatus();


}

void loop() {


          Udp.begin(localPort);
          Udp.beginPacket(destinationIP, destinationPort); 
          Udp.write("1");
          Udp.endPacket();
          Udp.stop();



}



void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();

  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");


}
```

I can't figure out how it's working one second, and not the next.

Comment: don't send so fast so many UDP messages

Comment: Did You try flush() on the server when finished with the packet?